# FreeRadius: Unable to delete unwanted attributes from Disconnect-Request

Tags: freeradius

I'm struggling to remove some unwanted attributes from the disconnect message emitted  after a failure in the rest module.

More specifically, in accounting mode, when I receive a Accounting-Request, I either return an Accounting-Response
or Disconnect-Request, depending on the HTTP status returned in a REST interaction. Both cases work properly, the only issue is
that the disconnect message also contains these attributes that nag NAS (they cause it to return a NAK):

```
NAS-Port
Teardown-Indicator (as 3GPP VSA)
```

These attributes are not present in the request. If they were, I could easily remove them and this would also affect the generated disconnect. But apparently, these attributes are added at some point that I have no control.
The "*update disconnect {...}*" has no effect, as I guess it is relevant only to received messages (not clear from the documentation).

I understand that disconenct belongs to a different connection, so it cannot be related and handled by tampering with 'reply' or anythig that freeradius provides me as variables. Still, I badly need to somehow solve the issue, as I have no control over the NAS itself.

Configuration details:

### mod rest:

```
accounting {
   uri = "http://x.x.x.x:yyyy/..."
   method = 'post'
   body = 'json'
   tls = ${..tls}
}
```

### sites default:

```
accounting {
    rest

    # this has no effect (same if placed inside rest {...}):
    update disconnect {
        NAS-Port !* ANY
        Teardown-Indicator !* ANY
    }
}
```

radius -X writes these:

```
(0) rest: Sending HTTP POST to "http://x.x.x.x:yyyy/..."
(0) rest: Encoding attribute "User-Name"
(0) rest: Encoding attribute "Framed-IP-Address"
(0) rest: Encoding attribute "Acct-Status-Type"
(0) rest: Encoding attribute "Acct-Session-Id"
(0) rest: Processing response header
(0) rest:   Status : 503 (Service Unavailable)
(0) rest: ERROR: Server returned no data
rlm_rest (rest): Released connection (0)
Need 5 more connections to reach 10 spares
rlm_rest (rest): Opening additional connection (5), 1 of 27 pending slots used
rlm_rest (rest): Skipping pre-connect, connect_uri not specified
(0)     [rest] = fail
(0)   } # accounting = fail
(0) WARNING: Unknown destination 127.0.0.1:3799 for CoA request.
(0) Not sending reply to client.
(0) Finished request
```

REST works OK and the 503 is expected for this particular case.
I cannot see something wrong (the ERROR and WARNING are not a huge surprise)

I wonder if there is some workaround to persuade freeradius not to add these naughty attributes, or otherwise, give me the chance to remove them?

Answer (score 0):

Eventually I clarified the way disconnect works. Freeradius is not adding any attributes by itself; all are configurable. The disconnect in my case was generated by another 'magic' element which I had no access to and ignored its presence.
All 'update' or 'filter' configuration should work correctly, but in my case I also needed to setup the originate-coa and home_server bits, which I didn't. If I try it I will post an update to explain how exactly it is done.